# MUI TextField Preventing Decimal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm trying to create customized Currency Input, but when ever i try to put decimal into value the textfield prevent it by typing, idk maybe there's a issue with my code.. Check the below code..

main.ts

```
  const [_val, setVal] = React.useState("");

  const handleChangeNumber = (e: any) => {
try {
  let s = e.target.value;

  let valueInNumber = Number(s.replaceAll(",",""));

  console.log(" << NUMBER >> ", valueInNumber);
  let formatedValue = numberFormatWithoutCurrency(valueInNumber as any);

  setVal(formatedValue as string);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
};
```

helperUtils.ts

```
export const numberFormatWithoutCurrency = (value: number) =>Intl.NumberFormat("en-US").format(value);
```

return =>

```
 <TextField
    value={_val}
    id={id}
    onChange={handleChangeNumber}
    type="text"
    fullWidth
  />
```

> Note: When i try the same code but comment the value from TextField it
> works fine..

> and it also works if you paste some value inclunding decimal('.')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `Intl.NumberFormat` is being run with a trailing period, so `0.` will be turned into `0`.

You can fix it by checking if the original text has a trailing period and putting it back.

```js
  let formatedValue = numberFormatWithoutCurrency(valueInNumber as any);

  if (s.endsWith(".")) {
    formatedValue += ".";
  }

  setVal(formatedValue); // You don't need to cast to string because it already is one
```

Comment: Ohh, okay now i get it.. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `handleChangeNumber` will be called with every change in the input field. Say, you want to enter a number 12.3, the `handleChangeNumber` will be called after each digit is keyed in i.e. in the order,

handleChangeNumber(1) 
handleChangeNumber(12) 
handleChangeNumber(12.)

```
let valueInNumber = Number(s.replaceAll(",",""));
```

Now, the above line will be run as `Number(12.)` which will return 12 and then you do `setValue(12)` which is why the dot disappears from your input!

When you directly paste the number 12.3 onto the TextField, the `handleChangeNumber()` now gets called with 12.3 as the argument, and hence the expected result.